# Lightning Sync has stopped working since Summer '23

Tags: calendar, google, sync, lightning-sync-configurations

We have Lightning Sync set up to sync Events (not Contacts) from Salesforce to Google Calendar. It has been working fine for years, but has not synced any events since June 9, 2023. I've double-checked that our service account is set up correctly. I've done the checklists outlined in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.exchange_sync_admin_check_status.htm&type=5 and https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383893&type=1

Google's API dashboard in the console show no API requests since June 9. When I check my user in the "User Sync Status" tool, this shows up:

```
Configuration Setup
User assigned to active Lightning Sync configuration:   Yes
User recognized by Google service account:  No

Events
Google Calendar™ found: ---
Salesforce and Google Enterprise™ account linked:   Linking
Salesforce to Google sync status:   Not started
Google to Salesforce sync status:   Lightning Sync configuration not set to sync
Records synced in last 24 hours:    0
Records in sync:    0
```

This is after resetting the sync for this user, and waiting a day. The `User recognized by Google service account:  No` seems significant, but I can find no information about what it means or how to fix it. When I type my email into the "Test Your Connection" input in another part of the setup interface, it says "We can’t connect with Google Calendar™. We can’t connect with Google Contacts."

I created a Lightning Sync Errors Report as detailed here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.exchange_sync_admin_error_report.htm&type=5 and I see some errors like `Error: Verify the login credentials for user ID <email>.` but only for my user, and these errors have happened since before we started seeing the sync problem. It's unclear why it'd use login credentials at all when the whole thing is run via service account.

It seems related to Summer '23, since sync stopped working after that upgrade.

It seems I'm not the only one having this problem: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000PfDfHSAV

I know that Salesforce wants everyone to use Einstein Activity Sync, but we'd have to pay more for it. I suspect that Lightning Sync has just...stopped working for everyone, at least on Google, and Salesforce isn't going to do anything about it, but is there any way I can debug this further?

Comment: Check [Lightning Sync for Google Error](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383893&type=1) and add calendar API scope(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just heard back from SF Support and they did confirm that it was related to Summer '23 and the workaround they proposed was to add the following auth scopes to the Google API client even if you're not syncing contacts.

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly

[image: sf reply]

This did the trick for our org and they are targeting a mid July fix for the bug.